# Integration by parts integrating with respect to CDF

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I am told that the following equality follows from integration by parts:

$$\int_{R-k}^{1}(\theta-R)dG(\theta)-G(R-k)k=\int_{R-k}^{1}(1-G(\theta))d\theta-k$$ Where $(R-k)\in[0,1)$ and $G$ is the CDF of $\theta$ which is distributed on $[0,1]$. I cannot, however, see how this is the case. Might someone explain how integration by parts has been used? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts takes the form of:

$\int_a^b v * du - (u*v) |_a^b = \int_a^b u * dv$

In this case, $u = -(1 - G(\theta))$ and $dv = d\theta$

$du = dG(\theta)$

$v = \theta$

$\int_a^b \theta dG(\theta) - (- ((1 - G(\theta)) * \theta))|_a^b - k = \int_a^b (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$\int_{R-k}^1 \theta dG(\theta) - (- ((1 - G(\theta)) * \theta))|_{R-k}^1 - k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$\int_{R-k}^1 \theta dG(\theta) + (1 - G(1)) - ((1 - G(R - k)) * (R -k) - k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$G(1) = 1$

$\int_{R-k}^1 \theta dG(\theta)  - R + k + G(R - k) * (R - k)- k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$\int_{R-k}^1 \theta dG(\theta)  - R * (G(R-k) - 1)  - G(R - k)* k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$\int_{R-k}^1 \theta dG(\theta)  - (R * G(\theta))|_{R-k}^1  - G(R - k)* k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$\int_{R-k}^1 \theta dG(\theta)  - \int_{R-k}^1 R dG(\theta)  - G(R - k)* k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$

$\int_{R-k}^1 (\theta - R) dG(\theta) - G(R - k)* k = \int_{R-k}^1 (1-G(\theta)) d\theta - k$